# Implementing Device-Specific Redirects in Angular Routing

Tags: angular, routes, device, detection, resolver

Problem Description:
I am facing challenges implementing device-specific redirects in Angular routing. I want to redirect users to different routes based on whether they are accessing the application from a desktop or mobile device.

Details:
In my Angular application, I need to redirect users to different routes depending on their device type. I have a service called ToolService with a method isDesktopOrTablet() to detect the device type accurately. Initially, I tried using class-based guards for redirection, but I discovered that they are deprecated. Then, I attempted to use a functional guard, but I encountered issues with canActivate and redirectTo not working together. Finally, I tried using a resolver to dynamically determine the redirect path based on the device type, but it doesn't seem to be executing as expected.

What I Tried:

Initially attempted to use class-based guards, but learned they are deprecated.
Tried using a functional guard, but encountered issues with canActivate and redirectTo.
Currently attempting to use a resolver to dynamically determine the redirect path based on device type.
Expected Outcome:
I expect the resolver to correctly determine the redirect path based on whether the user is on a desktop or mobile device and navigate the user accordingly. Additionally, I expect the redirection to occur seamlessly without any errors or issues.

What I Tried:
I attempted to implement device-specific redirects in Angular routing using different methods. Initially, I tried using class-based guards, but they are deprecated. Then, I tried using a functional guard, but encountered issues with canActivate and redirectTo not working together. Finally, I attempted to use a resolver to dynamically determine the redirect path based on device type.

Expected Outcome:
I expected the resolver to correctly determine the redirect path based on whether the user is on a desktop or mobile device and navigate the user accordingly. Additionally, I expected the redirection to occur seamlessly without any errors or issues.

Actual Result:
The resolver did not execute as expected, and the redirection did not occur as intended. The application stayed on the current route without redirecting to the desired route based on the device type.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some code so we can help you.

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example of your issue on https://codesandbox.io/. This will allow the community to better understand the specific challenges you're facing and offer more targeted assistance.